# Evaluating overlap of number ranges in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, range, comparison

Assume a text file `file` which contains multiple lines of number ranges. The lower and upper bound of each range are separated by a dash, and the individual ranges are sorted (i.e., range 101-297 comes before 1299-1314).

```
$cat file
101-297
1299-1314
1301-5266
6898-14503
```

How can I confirm in **bash** if one or more of these number ranges are overlapping?

In my opinion, all that is needed seems to be to iteratively perform integer comparisons across adjacent lines. The individual integer comparisons could look like something like this:

```
if [ "$upperbound_range1" -gt "$lowerbound_range2" ]; then
    echo "Overlap!"
    exit 1
fi
```

I suspect, however, that this comparison can also be done via *awk*.

*Note:* Ideally, the code could not only determine if any of the ranges is overlapping with its immediate successor range, but also which range is the overlapping one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in awk.

```
awk -F"-" 'Q>=$1 && Q{print}{Q=$NF}'   Input_file
```

Making here -(dash) as a field separator then checking if a variable named Q is NOT NULL and it's value is greater then current line's first field($1) is yes then print that line(if you want to print previous line we could do that also), now create/re-assign variable Q's value to current line's last field's value.

**EDIT:** As per OP user wants to get the previous line so changing it to that now too.

```
awk -F"-" 'Q>=$1 && Q{print val}{Q=$NF;val=$0}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Yes, how would you modify the print statement to print the previous instead of the current line?

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl: kindly check my edited answer now and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Works nicely! Thank you.

Comment: Please see my follow-up question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763337/discrete-to-continuous-number-ranges-via-awk). I would appreciate your input!

Comment: Answered there too :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$ awk -F"-" '$1<last_2 && NR>1 {printf "%s: %s: Overlap\n", last_line, $0} 
                             {last_line=$0; last_2=$2}' file
1299-1314: 1301-5266: Overlap
```

Answer (score 0):

If ranges are sorted by lower bound, and there's a range which overlaps, then the overlapping range will be the successor.

```
ranges=( $(<file) )

# or ranges=(101-297 1299-1314 1301-5266 6898-14503)

for ((i=1;i<${#ranges[@]};i+=1)); do
    range=${ranges[i-1]}
    succesorRange=${ranges[i]}
    if ((${range#*-}>=${succesorRange%-*})); then
        echo "overlap $i $range $succesorRange"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you, but have you tested this code? The loop does not seem to iterate over the ranges, it seems. `for ((i=1; i<${#ranges[@]}; i+=1)); do echo $i; done`

Comment: ok it seems parentheses missing on array initialization on the first line checked with the commented line : `ranges=( $(<file) )` instead of `ranges=$(<file)`