# Discrete to continuous number ranges via awk

Tags: bash, awk, integer, range, continuous

Assume a text file `file` which contains multiple discrete number ranges, one per line. Each range is preceded by a string (i.e., the range name). The lower and upper bound of each range is separated by a dash. Each number range is succeeded by a semi-colon. The individual ranges are sorted (i.e., range 101-297 comes before 1299-1301) and do not overlap.

```
$cat file
foo  101-297;
bar  1299-1301;
baz  1314-5266;
```

Please note that in the example above the three ranges do not form a continuous range that starts at integer 1.

I believe that **awk** is the appropriate tool to fill the missing number ranges such that all ranges taken together form a continuous range from {1} to {upper bound of the last range}. If so, what awk command/function would you use to perform the task?

```
$cat file | sought_awk_command
new1 1-100;
foo  101-297;
new2 298-1298;
bar  1299-1301;
new3 1302-1313;
baz  1314-5266;
```

--

**Edit 1**: Upon closer evaluation, the code suggested below fails at another simple example.

```
$cat example2
foo  101-297;
bar  1299-1301;
baz  1302-1314; # Notice that ranges "bar" and "baz" are continuous to one another
qux  1399-5266;

$ awk -F'[ -]' '$3-Q>1{print "new"++o,Q+1"-"$3-1";";Q=$4} 1' example2
new1 1-100;
foo  101-297;
new2 298-1298;
bar  1299-1301;
baz  1302-1314;
new3 1302-1398; # ERROR HERE: Notice that range "new3" has a lower bound that is equal to upper bound of "bar", not of "baz".
qux  1399-5266;
```

--

**Edit 2:** Many thanks to [RavinderSingh13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5866580/ravindersingh13) for assistance with solving this question. However, the suggested code still generates output inconsistent with the given objective.

```
$ cat example3
foo  35025-35144;
bar  35259-35375;
baz  35376-35624;
qux  37911-39434;

$ awk -F'[ -]' '$3-Q+0>=1{print "new"++o,Q+1"-"$3-1";";Q=$4} {Q=$4;print}' example3
new1 1-35024;
foo  35025-35144;
new2 35145-35258;
bar  35259-35375;
new3 35376-35375; # ERROR HERE: Notice that range "new3" has been added, even though ranges "bar" and "baz" are contiguous.
baz  35376-35624;
new4 35625-37910;
qux  37911-39434;
```

Comment: You said "The individual ranges are sorted (i.e., range 101-297 comes before 1299-1301) and **do not overlap**." but then posted `example2` where they **do** overlap (`bar  1299-1301;` and `baz  1301-1314;` overlap at `1301`). Do they or do they not overlap? Also - **awk is not a bash tool**, it's a completely independent tool available on all standard UNIX installations and for some other OSes.

Comment: @EdMorton The ranges do not overlap. `example2` contains a mistake. My bad. It should read `bar 1299-1301` and `baz 1302-1314`. I have corrected the example accordingly. Point also taken regarding `bash` as a UNIX (and not specifically bash) tool.

Comment: no problem, the script I posted will work either way.

Comment: What is the desired output for data: `1-100`. `102-200`, ie. when there is only one value available between the ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has no problem with ranges that can overlap as you showed in your original example2 where `bar 1299-1301;` and `baz 1301-1314;` overlapped at `1301`.

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ split($2,curr,/[-;]/); currStart=curr[1]; currEnd=curr[2] }
currStart > (prevEnd+1) { print "new"++cnt, prevEnd+1 "-" currStart-1 ";" }
{ print; prevEnd=currEnd }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
new1 1-100;
foo  101-297;
new2 298-1298;
bar  1299-1301;
new3 1302-1313;
baz  1314-5266;

$ awk -f tst.awk example2
new1 1-100;
foo  101-297;
new2 298-1298;
bar  1299-1301;
baz  1301-1314;
new3 1315-1398;
qux  1399-5266;

$ awk -f tst.awk example3
new1 1-35024;
foo  35025-35144;
new2 35145-35258;
bar  35259-35375;
baz  35376-35624;
new3 35625-37910;
qux  37911-39434;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code alternative. As I am trying to avoid any extra files in the working directory (i.e., `tst.awk`), how can I apply your three-liner without having to save it to file and invoking the `-f` flag?

Comment: In general `awk 'script' file` instead of `awk -f script_in_file file` So in this case `awk '{ split($2,curr,/[-;]/); currStart=curr[1]; currEnd=curr[2] }
currStart > (prevEnd+1) { print "new"++cnt, prevEnd+1 "-" currStart-1 ";" }
{ print; prevEnd=currEnd }' file`. You might benefit from simply saving and executing it in a different directory though so you have it to re-use and build on later, e.g. `awk -f "$HOME/bin/tst.awk" file`. You can of course make all the variable names single letters if for some reason you prefer brevity over clarity.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
awk -F'[ -]' '$3-Q>1{print "new"++o,Q+1"-"$3-1";";Q=$4} 1'   Input_file
```

**EDIT:** Adding a non-one liner solution for same too now with proper explanation.

```
awk -F'[ -]' '                                        ###Setting field separator as space, dash here.
                $3-Q>1{                               ###Checking here if 3rd field and variable Qs subtraction is greater than 1, if yes then perform following.
                        print "new"++o,Q+1"-"$3-1";"; ###printing the string new with a incrementing value of variable o each time, then variable Qs value with adding 1 to it, then current line $4-1 and semi colon.
                        Q=$4                          ###Assigning the variable Q value to 4th field of the current line here too.
                      }
                1                                     ###printing the current line here.
             ' Input_file                             ###Mentioning the Input_file here too.
```

**EDIT2:** Adding one more answer as per OP's a condition.

```
 awk -F'[ -]' '$3-Q+0>=1{print "new"++o,Q+1"-"$3-1";";Q=$4} {Q=$4;print}'   Input_file
```

Comment: Excellent explanation! However, the upper bound of each inserted range (i.e., newX) should be one less than the lower (not the upper!) bound of the subsequent range.

Comment: Apologies for that, changed it accordingly now.

Comment: Wow! You definitely know awk!

Comment: there could more than 2 spaces - in that case `$4` will be empty. I would use `-F'[[:space:]]*|-'`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Upon closer evaluation, I noticed that your code fails at a second, equally simple example. Please see my post at CodeReview for the exact problem (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166982/code-to-convert-discrete-to-continuous-number-ranges-via-awk). Would you have a suggestion on how to correct the issue?

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl: try my latest edited now, also in that site I have poted solution too but seems it came from some other user, kindly check and let me know on same.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Many thanks for your assistance! However, your revised code still generates output inconsistent with the given objective. Please see my edit #2 for an example. Would you please take another look at it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file1
foo  2-100
bar  102-200
$ awk F' +|[-;}' 'p+1<$2{print "new" ++q, p+1 "-" $2-1 ";"}p=$3' file1
new1 1-1;
foo  2-100
new2 101-101;
bar  102-200
$ cat file2
foo  101-297;
bar  1299-1301;
baz  1314-5266;
$ awk -F' +|[-;]' 'p+1<$2{print "new" ++q, p+1 "-" $2-1 ";"}p=$3' file2
new1 1-100;
foo  101-297;
new2 298-1298;
bar  1299-1301;
new3 1302-1313;
baz  1314-5266;
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -F' +|[-;]' '                   # FS is ; - or a bunch of spaces
p+1 < $2 {                           # if p revious $3+1 is still less than new $2
    print "new"++q,p+1 "-" $2-1 ";"  # print a "new" line
}
p=$3                                 # set future p and implicit print of record *
' file2                              # * as all values are above 0
```

Comment: I think `awk -F '[+;-]' …` is slightly faster than your field separator since character classes are faster than alternations (note the dash must be last in order to prevent denoting a range of characters).  I think it also solves a typo in your code (unless you meant to delimit on ` +` rather than without the leading space like `+`).

Comment: @AdamKatz I did actually: _`FS is ; - or a bunch of spaces`_

Comment: ah, I see now.  In that case, `-F' +|[;-]'` would be preferable.