# Intersect/join comma-separated lists of ranges (1,2,4-5) in bash

Tags: bash, list, algorithm, range

I'm dealing with data structures that are basically lists of sorted, non-overlapping integer ranges:

```
1,2,3
```

```
1-5
```

```
0,1,3-4,6,8-10
```

I need to perform basic operations (union and intersection) on pairs of these lists, e. g.:

```
$ list_and '1,2,3' '0,1,3-4,6,8-10'
1,3

$ list_or  '1-5'   '0,1,3-4,6,8-10'
0-6,8-10
```

I can construct each set explicitly in an associative array, perform the operation on pairs of members and then collapse the result set back into this form, but it would be prohibitively slow for large ranges.

What would be the most efficient way to join and intersect such "lists of ranges" in pure Bash?

Comment: Bash is inherently slow. Why can't you do this in another language?

Comment: What's the expected output for the given lists?

Comment: A simple solution in Awk or Python would probably be a better approach than bare Bash.

Comment: I'd probably: **a)** process each list item as a min/max pair (for `1,2-6` => first item has `min=max=1`, second item has `min=2,max=6`), **b)** walk down both lists (think 'merge/join') while **c)** performing some conditional logic (`case/switch` statement?) to determine new ranges (again, min/max pair); this should eliminate the overhead of expanding/processing/collapsing (large? huge?) ranges

Comment: the obvious (?) hard part is going to be the conditional logic to compare overlapping ranges which shouldn't be too hard to work through a few sample cases; a google search on processing overlapping ranges brings up quite a few hits, eg: [so #1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46033946), [so #2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12742484), [so #3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44761166)

Answer (score 0):

Set operations would be a lot easier with the help of commands like `join(1)`, `comm(1)` and `sort(1)`, but they're doable in nothing but `bash`. I do agree with oguz that another language would be more appropriate. You can get very fancy and efficient sparse integer sets using better data structures than what shells support.

Splitting the input ranges up into lines of individual numbers to serve as input to those programs is pretty easy too with some shell arithmetic.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Turn a string like 1,3,5-10 into one number per line, filling in ranges
expand() {
    local IFS=,
    # For each comma-separated element
    for elem in $1; do
        # If it's a range, print out each number in the range
        if [[ $elem =~ ([0-9]+)-([0-9]+) ]]; then
            for (( i = BASH_REMATCH[1]; i <= BASH_REMATCH[2]; i++ )); do
                printf "%d\n" "$i"
            done
        else
            # And if it's just a scalar, print that number.
            printf "%d\n" "$elem"
        fi
    done
}

list_and() {
    # Add each element in the first argument to an associate array,
    # and then for each element of the second argument, see if it also
    # exists in that array. If so, add it to the result.

    local -A arr1
    for elem in $(expand "$1"); do
        arr1[$elem]=1
    done
    
    local -a intersection
    for elem in $(expand "$2"); do
        if [[ -v arr1[$elem] ]]; then
            intersection+=("$elem")
        fi  
    done

    local IFS=,
    printf "%s\n" "${intersection[*]}"
}

list_or() {
    # Populate a sparse array using the numbers from arguments
    # as indexes.
    
    local -a union
    for elem in $(expand "$1") $(expand "$2"); do
        union[$elem]=$elem
    done

    local IFS=,
    printf "%s\n" "${union[*]}"
}

printf "%s\n" "$(list_and '1,2,3' '0,1,3-4,6,8-10')"
printf "%s\n" "$(list_or '1-5' '0,1,3-4,6,8-10')"
```

Converting things like `1,2,3` into `1-3` in the output is left as an exercise for the reader. (I don't want to do *all* your homework for you...)

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I already have: _"I can construct each set explicitly in an associative array, perform the operation on pairs of members and then collapse the result set back into this form"_. Was wondering if there were any clever (and simple enough to code) algorithms. Also, not a homework.

Comment: @intelfx There's only one associative array in the above. And now that I think of it, it can be changed to a regular array.

Comment: yes, it can. If the input is sorted, you can iterate over the expansions in a lock-step. It’s still the same general idea.